# Add Grid Widget as custom form field

Tags: grid, ee-1.13, offers

I'm adding a feature in a custom module that should manage Offer incompatibilities: for a given offer ID, there could be N "incompatibility" rules.

Basically, the model is:

```
OfferID    IncompatibleOfferID    Active(Y/N)
----------------------------------------------
1          13                     Y
1          22                     Y
2          21                     N
```

So, for a given rule you can have multiple association between offers.

In the Edit form I would like to have a grid (Widget) to select multiple "child" offers to bind with the "father" offer.

To achieve that, I created:

[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/[MyModule]/Edit/Offer/Grid.php

that is basically a Grid Widget, in fact it has all the grid methods like

```
public function _prepareCollection()
{
    $items = Mage::getModel('offer/offer')->getCollection();

    $this->setCollection($items);
}
```

Now I would like to add this grid to the Edit form to select multiple "child" offer at the time.

So, here is my [Module]/Block/Adminhtml/[MyModule]/Edit/Form.php :

```
    /** @var Varien_Data_Form $form */
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ));

/** ETC ETC **/

$promoFieldset = $form->addFieldset('related_promo', array(
            'legend' => Mage::helper('offer')->__('Promozioni'))
        );

$relatedProdsGrid = $this
    ->getLayout()
     ->createBlock('offer/adminhtml_compatibleoffer_edit_offer_grid')
     ;

   $promoFieldset->addElement($relatedProdsGrid);
```

The last line is giving me the error, because "addElement" method accept only Varien_Form_Data_Abstract as input. Plus, the grid is not working as it should, (no filter, no pagination, no limit)

Any ideas? Should I choose a different approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a multi-tabbed edit form, and configure a new tab to ONLY contain the grid.

Essentially you are creating a tab class that uses this declaration:

```
class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Something_Edit_Tab_Subelements
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {}
```

This tab extends from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` instead of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`.

Examples:

- Edit Customer (Orders Tab, Shopping Cart Tab, etc)
- Edit Product (Related Products Tab, etc)
- Order View (Invoice, Shipments, etc are all grids inside a "form")